# Does airbrake reduce or increase static pressure downstream of it?

Tags: aerodynamics, separation

When airbrake is down, flow is fully attached on upper surface, when airbrake lift up flow separate.

Is static pressure at point 2  and 3 now lower or higher compare when airbrake is down?

[CFD video separation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ti5zUD08w5s)

[image]

To me seems that separation reduce suction at nose to 1/4 part but increase suction from 1/4 to trailing edge, both contribute to increase in drag?

Comment: Is this a [homework question](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4306/7532)?